# Infinite call of Keyevent on Ubuntu

Tags: java, awt, ubuntu-12.04, keyevent, awtrobot

I need to create key event on host computer. 
So, I made a simple java code like this.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
        try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F11);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

When I execute this code on windows using `Eclipse`, `keyevent` for `F11` is triggered just one time 5 seconds later. 
However, when I execute this on `Ubuntu(12.04)` using `Eclipse` or commands (`javac` and `java`), 
the `keyevent` seems to be triggered continuously. (it seems to go into infinite loop) 
Java version was `1.6 and 1.7 on Ubuntu`.

I don;t know why this happens. Anybody knows a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to release the key as well (to simulate a key type)...

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F11);
Thread.sleep(250);    
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F11);
```

Other wise the system will think you're holding the key down...

ps- I find adding a small delay helps improve the overall functionality.  You can set a automatic delay directly within the Robot.  See [`Robot#setAutoDelay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#setAutoDelay%28int%29) for more details

Comment: Oh! It works! I appreciate it!! Also, Thanks for additional information.

Answer (score 1):

As said [in the JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#keyPress%28int%29), you have to "release" the key after pressing it :

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F11);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F11);
```

It remains "pressed" until you release it.